# Play doesn't convert java-list to scala-list

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a controller which hands a java-list of model-objects to the view exactly the way like it's done in the examples.

The compiler throws an error that it can't convert from `java.util.List` to `scala.collection.immutable.List`. I have no clue what I should do.

```
[error] /myapp/myappsubprojects/frontend/app/controllers/frontend/MyController.java:15: error: method render in class linklist cannot be applied to given types;
[error]         return ok(linklist.render("link test", Link.findAll()));
[error]                           ^
[error]   required: String,scala.collection.immutable.List<Link>
[error]   found: String,java.util.List<Link>
[error]   reason: actual argument java.util.List<Link> cannot be converted to scala.collection.immutable.List<Link> by method invocation conversion
[error] 1 error
```

Note: I'm using subprojects (common, frontend, backend) and I had a hard time to make everything run properly. Probably it's related to that.

Comment: Do you have a `templatesImport` setting in your main project's `Build.scala` file? `java.util.*` should normally get automatically imported into each view template, one reason it might not however is if you override the list of default imports in your build file.

Comment: That was the solution! Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went fishing for details and ended up (luckily) answering the question in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116264/play-doesnt-convert-java-list-to-scala-list?noredirect=1#comment23021814_16116264)