# Play! failing to convert java list to scala list

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to pass a list of strings from my java controller to the scala template.
This is the view code:

```
public static Result index() {
    List<String> scripts = Arrays.asList(
        "script1.js",
        ...
        "scriptN.js"
    );

    return ok(views.html.index.render(scripts));
}
```

and this is the tempate code:

```
@(scripts: List[String])

@main("test page")(scripts) {
    ... html here ...
}
```

The error I'm getting (in the Typesafe Activation Compile page):

> method render in class index cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: scala.collection.immutable.List
>   found: java.util.List
>   reason: actual argument java.util.List cannot be converted to scala.collection.immutable.List by
>   method invocation conversion

Is there a way to solve it without using the java > scala conversions?
I found this question: [Play doesn't convert java-list to scala-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116264/play-doesnt-convert-java-list-to-scala-list) which describes a similar situation, though I do not have any templateImports that I'm aware of, I don't even see a Build.scala file...

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating over Java collections in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495741/iterating-over-java-collections-in-scala)

Comment: @om-nom-nom my question is in the context of Play! framework, the other one isn't...  As I wrote, I'd like to avoid using the converters if there's a play! way of doing things. Because of that I do not think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @om-nom-nom It is different. Here he wishes to access Scala collection from Java and not vice-versa as mentioned in the link

Comment: @Jatin he has Scala list on the receiver end (no matter which language) and tries to push java list into it. I don't see how it is different from trying to iterate java list in scala-like way (and even if he has the opposite situation it is still, very likely, a duplicate)

Comment: Could you use `@(scripts: java.util.List[String])` and convert it there if needed? It should just be `scripts.asScala.toList` after importing `JavaConverters._`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;

public static Result index() {
    List<String> scripts = Arrays.asList(
        "script1.js",
        ...
        "scriptN.js"
    );
    scala.collection.immutable.List<String> ls = JavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter(scripts).asScala().toList();
    return ok(views.html.index.render(ls));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There's no `toList` method, there's `asScala` but it returns `Buffer<String>`

Comment: Oh. never mind, I just need to use both... `JavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter(scripts).asScala().toList()`

Comment: @NitzanTomer Sorry it was a mistake. It is `asScala().toList()`. This will work

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a bit more time since I'd prefer to avoid using `JavaConverters` if there's a better approach in play!.  If nothing better presents itself I'll mark your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 2):

try below in your template code :

```
@import java.util   
@(scripts: util.List[String])
```

Comment: This appears to fix the problem for me, but I don't understand why it fixes it, can you explain?